Configuring Drupal 10 Multisite on a Single Domain
I'm encountering an issue with my Drupal 10 multisite setup. The requirement is to host all instances of the site on one domain, but with different URL prefixes:
site.com/ua
site.com/fr
site.com/uk
My question is: do I need to configure separate routes in nginx/apache for each URL prefix to specify the directory of the respective subsite? Currently, I'm facing a problem where, on the base URL (site.com/), the main site loads fine, but when accessing the multisite at site.com/ua, for example, it returns a 404. (Interestingly, on a separate domain, the subsite works perfectly.)
I've already added the following in site.php:
For URL site.com/ua - subdirectory web/sites/siteua
$sites['site.com.ua'] = 'siteua';
Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Which domain works perfectly? Yes you usually make symlinks to do this. Search for “path-based multisite”.

Hi @cilefen, thank you for your attention.
I'm currently focused on this decision, unfortunately nothing is working out yet
https://samwaters.net/nginx-drupal-9-multisite-and-path-based-urls/
Unfortunately, my subpaths are interpreted as pages of the main site
